# Hide scrollbar in IE 11, but achieve IE effect

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I have a navigation in my site that contains multiple items. Depending on the screensize, many items can be offscreen and a user can scroll across.

I have an issue in IE where the scrollbar appears on screen, and I can't hide it without losing the scroll effect.

Any ideas?

I'm using the following in chrome to hide my scroll bars

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

I've made a js fiddle with my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/6p1Lnosa/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to scroll the content on the x axis in IE 11? If so, you can refer to the following method:

1. In parent div, we can hide scroll-bar and for preventing showing it again when we change child scrollbar position programmatically: set its box limit to `-ms-scroll-limit: 0 0 0 0`:

   ```
   #parent_div:{
   overflow: hidden; 
   -ms-scroll-limit:0 0 0 0; /* IE 11 */
   }
   ```
2. In child div, we can hide scrollbar and control a scroll-bar programmatically:

   ```
   #child_div:{
     -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 11 */
   }
   ```

I edit the following parts in your code then it can achieve what you want in IE:

```
.desktop-nav {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    /*overflow: scroll;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-scroll-limit: 0 0 0 0; /* IE 11 */
}

.desktop-nav ul {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 11 */
 }
```

Result in IE 11:
[image]